# Boto3 unable to connect to local DynamoDB running in Docker container

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm at a complete loss. I have a Docker container running DynamoDB locally. From the terminal window, I run:

`docker run -p 8010:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local`

to start the container. It starts fine. I then run:

`aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8010`

to verify that the container and the local instance is working fine. I get:

```py
{
   "TableNames": []
}
```

That's exactly what I expect. It tells me that the aws client can connect to the local DB instance properly.

Now the problem. I get to a python shell, and type:

```py
import boto3
db = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1', endpoint_url='http://localhost:8010', use_ssl=False, aws_access_key_id='my_secret_key', aws_secret_access_key='my_secret_access_key', verify=False)
print(db.list_tables())
```

I get a ConnectionRefusedError. I have tried the connection with and without the secret keys, with and without use_ssl and verify, and nothing works. At this point I'm thinking it must be a bug with boto3. What am I missing?

Comment: I figured it out. I was inside another docker container trying to connect from python in that container, which I haven't yet set up. Once I switched to my local host environment, I was able to connect with boto3.