# not being able to create table locally when running DynamoDB local on Docker

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a Django App
Here is my code:

```
def get(self, request):
  dynamo_db = boto3.resource(
      "dynamodb",
      region_name="localhost",
      aws_access_key_id=os.getenv("ACCESS_KEY"),
      aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv("SECRET_KEY"),
      endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000",
  )

 table = dynamo_db.create_table(
            TableName="CustomUsers_Duplicate",
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {"AttributeName": "username", "AttributeType": "S"},
            ],
            KeySchema=[
                {"AttributeName": "username", "KeyType": "HASH"},
            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput={"ReadCapacityUnits": 1, "WriteCapacityUnits": 1},
        )
  return Response("Inside GET endpoint")
```

Every time when I hit the endpoint, I kept getting an error

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:8000/"
```

But I don't see any issue when running

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

My docker config

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  moof-backend-app:
    build: .
    container_name: moof-backend-app
    image: moof-backend-app:eb-cli-installed
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/moof-backend
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    depends_on:
      - dynamodb-local

  dynamodb-local:
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "./docker/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
```

Interestingly enough, if I erase `endpoint_url`, the table was successfully created on the DynamoDB of the associated IAM account.

What is the problem here?

Edited:

The error occurs at the very top looks like this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
moof-backend-app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
moof-backend-app    |     conn = connection.create_connection(
moof-backend-app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
moof-backend-app    |     raise err
moof-backend-app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
moof-backend-app    |     sock.connect(sa)
moof-backend-app    | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: You need to share your docker config settings. Also, is the credentials the same for boto3 and in your cli?

Comment: updated the docker config...as for the credentials, i think they are the same

Comment: Thanks. Can you try create a table using the CLI and the local endpoint.

Comment: just tested out, creating table works with CLI, but just doesnt work with my code

Comment: I also elaborated a bit more on the type of error i was getting

Comment: Please try replacing "localhost" in your endpoint_url to 127.0.0.1. Might be a IPv6 issue...

Comment: tried and still didn't work. looks like there IS some issue with establishing connection to DynamoDB local when running server on docker container. after i switched to local environment from container, it is working fine. Also just found this thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64109828/boto3-unable-to-connect-to-local-dynamodb-running-in-docker-container

Comment: Your dynamo container name is `dynamodb-local` so the connection URL should be `http://dynamodb-local:8000`

Comment: holy moly, this one worked..could you please put your reply as the answer to this question? also, if i change that to ```http://dynamodb-local:8000``` , what CLI should i run to see the list of tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DynamoDB container name is `dynamodb-local`, so the connection URL **from the service container** should be `http://dynamodb-local:8000`. This is explained in https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking:

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

In response to your comment:

> also, if i change that to http://dynamodb-local:8000 , what CLI should i run to see the list of tables?

If you are running the CLI on your host machine, outside of Docker, use `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`.